# fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica always returning zero

Tags: sql-server-2012, high-availability

I'm setting up a SQL Server 2012 "Always On" availability group and I am having issues with the backup maintenance plan.

I've tracked the problem down to fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica always returning zero

I created a test database and ran the function, it returned 1.
I then added the database to the availability group and the function returned zero.
I've tried every option in Backup Preferences and in all cases on both primary and secondary instances, it returns zero. It never returns 1.

Comment: Do you only have a single replica? What are the backup priority values for each replica?

Comment: Single replica. Tried it with 100/0, 50/50, 51/49. No effect.

Comment: So why are you worried about this function until you have more than one replica and are actually running backup scripts that need to care?

Comment: Actually it's two replicas. I thought you meant in addition to the primary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discovered the problem. It relates to changing the server name.
The network engineer who built the cluster changed this value after the build.
We started from scratch and it now works.

Comment: Yep, renaming a server and not properly updating the catalog can lead to problems. For example in this DMV there is this code: `if (@primary_server_name = @local_server_name)`...

Answer (score 0):

@@Servername of null can happen if there is no entry in sys.servers for server_id 0.  check sys.servers with this:

select * from sys.servers where server_id=0

If this returns 0 rows you can add the local server with

sp_addserver '', local

you will need to restart the server for this to take effect.

You may also need to remove your server being > row 0 EXEC sp_dropserver 'old_name';